# Azure media player preview image

Tags: azure, media-player

Is there a way to specify the poster or get the preview image of the video from the azure media player as mentioned on this page

http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Use the "poster" attribute on the video tag.

For example:

```
<video id="azuremediaplayer" poster="~/Content/img/preview.png" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered"  controls width="640" height="480" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false}, "nativeControlsForTouch": false}' tabindex="0">
    <source src="{video_src}" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
</video>
```

If you don't specify a value for the poster attribute then the player will use the first frame of the source video as the poster.